# How should I assess a model in the presence of large irreducible noise in my training data?

Tags: r, model

Suppose my target variable $Y$ is generated from $X$ through a simple linear relationship but with large noise $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ with $\sigma >> Y$:

$$Y = 0.1 \times X + N(0, 100), X \in [0, 10]$$

Plotting $Y$ against $X$ shows mostly noise:

[image]

When I fit a linear model, I get a pretty accurate estimate of the coefficient $0.093 \pm 0.035$. But all the "traditional" model accuracy metrics have terrible values; for example, $R^2 = 0.0007$ and I find it very difficult to convince stakeholders that such models are the best we can do, and are in fact adequate because we are interested in estimating the main effects, not necessarily achieving high accuracy for individual points.

How should I deal with such situations, when the target variable is plagued with large irreducible noise but I'd like to know whether the model accurately estimates the main effects? (Note that I'd ideally like a method that also works with non-parametric models such as random forests, so I can't look at p-values or t-values.)

Here's the R code for this example:

```
n <- 10000
x <- runif(n, 0, 10)
y <- 0.1 * x + rnorm(n, 0, 10)
plot(x, y)
fit <- lm(y ~ x)
summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-35.168  -6.850  -0.008   6.861  38.626 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept) -0.02196    0.20184  -0.109  0.91335   
x            0.09296    0.03507   2.651  0.00805 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 10.09 on 9998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0007022, Adjusted R-squared:  0.0006023 
F-statistic: 7.026 on 1 and 9998 DF,  p-value: 0.008046
```

Comment: If your point is to prove that a linear model provides a better fit to the data than more complicated models (such as higher order polynomials), one idea would be to use model comparison tools, such as the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC). It compares the competing models based on their ability to fit the data, while penalizing for the complexity (i.e. the number of parameters) to avoid overfitting. The problem is that, with such a high noise, a "constant" model (i.e. a zero-order polynomial where $Y \approx 0$) will probably win over your linear model.

Comment: @CamilleGontier good point but in this case the linear model is the best one (its BIC is 74627.57, that of `y ~ 0` is 74635.31). As far as I know metrics like the BIC (or the R2, for that matter) can only help me select between competing models, but cannot say if a model is good enough.

Comment: Be careful that the BIC for the constant model should not be evaluated at $Y = 0$, but at $Y = \hat{\theta}$, where $\hat{\theta}$ is the maximum likelihood estimator for your model (which, I guess, will be slightly superior to 0 in your case). This may affect the result. I agree that one of the cons of the BIC is that it only provides a relative score: perhaps you can argue that, by looking at the data, only low order polynomials are likely to be useful ?

Comment: @CamilleGontier oh I'm sorry, I should have used `y ~ 1` and then the BIC is 74625.39, i.e. slightly lower than for `y ~ x`.

Comment: I think you are already quite close to a feasible solution. Move the focus on the ability of the model to accurately estimate the effect you are interested in e.g. by showing a 95% confidence interval for the true slope. Ideally, the full range of that interval would mean a "good" effect in terms of the stakeholders.

Comment: @lindelof are you sure the MLE for the constant model is at 1 ? Intuitively, I would have guessed it should be close to the expected value for $Y$, i.e. $E(Y) = 0.5$

Comment: @CamilleGontier The `y ~ 1` model formula just means fitting the intercept, which the model finds as `Y = 0.44`. Then I call R's `BIC()` function on the fitted model. I'm pretty sure this estimated the BIC at the MLE.

Comment: Ok ! Running the simulations myself, I find that which model provides the best BIC varies with generated data set. On the one hand, the noise is really high (favoring the constant one), but on the other hand, having a large number of data points favors the linear one.